# Angular HttpInterceptor, получить статус от запроса несмотря на ошибку или 201

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular5, spa

```
   addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string|null): HttpRequest<any> {
        return req.clone({ setHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }})
      } 



intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return next.handle(this.addToken(req, this.Token.accessToken())).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
            case 400:
              return this.handle400Error(error);
            case 401:
              return this.handle401Error(req, next);
            default:
              return observableThrowError(error);
          }
        } else {
          return observableThrowError(error);
        }
      }));
}
```

catchError выдает ошибку типов, другой способ кроме catchError есть, чтобы поймать 401 статус и message от backend?

Comment: Не знаю как, но если в catchError error, возвратит string, то ошибка проподет, но это не решение